# How to create a new array from another array recursive

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to write a method that finds all odd integers from an array and returns a new array with that integers.

Comment: Have you thought about creating an ArrayList (which you don't have to define the size of) to add the elements to. You can then easily use the `toArray()` method provided with the ArrayList class which will allow you to convert from an ArrayList to an array.

Comment: @Jay This sounds like an early academic exercise, they may not have been introduced to ArrayLists yet

Comment: in your progam can you use other available in Java collections? Because you need to use a "dynamic array" conception in your filterOddHelp. there is no such thing in Java as "dynamic array" so easiest way is to use ArrayList instead. If your assignment to use array only then there is a solution with System.arraycopy method to achive "dynamic array" functionality.

Comment: ... or, if you absolutely need to use arrays in the recursion, create your return array once, as a copy of the input `m`, in your `filterOdd` function and don't keep creating it anew on each iteration. At each step increase `i` if the value was odd, or swap it with the last (`j`th) element and decrease `j` otherwise. Then at the end you will need to trim your array based on the final `i` or `j` value.

Comment: @JonK You are right. I was trying to figure out a way to explain it without giving away the answer because I thought it might be a valuable learning exercise!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are initializing your return array at the same size of the input x array. int[] will default its values to 0.

What you should do is if you find an odd, then subtract the size by one, then initialize the array, this way you wont have "empty" bins that are defaulted to 0

Answer (score -1):

When you are searching for some kind of answer and you do not know the exact size it is a good idea to use `List` for example `ArrayList` which can help in your case:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        List<Integer> result = filterOdd(a);
        for (Integer i : result) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer> filterOdd(int[] m) {
        return filterOddHelp(m, 0, m.length - 1);
    }

    public static List<Integer> filterOddHelp(int[] x, int i, int j) {
        List<Integer> returnArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (i <= j) {
            returnArray = filterOddHelp(x, i + 1, j);
            if (x[i] % 2 != 0) {
                returnArray.add(x[i]);
            }
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

Console:

```
9
7
5
3
1
```

Consider using `List` when you do not know how big of an array you will need.

Comment: I've downvoted because I don't feel that in this case giving out the finished, working code is the right thing to be doing. This reads like a homework question, so the answer would be more beneficial if it described potential solutions to the problem but stopped short of actually solving it so that the asker has the opportunity to figure it out for themselves. Bear in mind that you might actually be working with this person in 5 years time (unlikely but still) - you want them to be good programmers instead of good at asking for help on stackoverflow!